# build.sh ios generates "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" when using XCode6 Beta6

Tags: realm, xcode6-beta6

on a fresh checkout of realm master from github, I run the following command:

```
XCODE_VERSION=6 sh build.sh ios
```

Which results in the following error....

```
ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_swift_stdlib_atomicCompareExchangeStrongPtr", referenced from:
      __TFVSs11_StringCore14_claimCapacityfRS_FTSi15minElementWidthSi_TSiVSs14COpaquePointer_ in RLMSwiftSupport.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/DerivedData/Realm-Xcode6/Build/Intermediates/Realm-Xcode6.build/Release-iphoneos/iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Realm normal arm64
    Ld build/DerivedData/Realm-Xcode6/Build/Intermediates/Realm-Xcode6.build/Release-iphoneos/iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Realm normal armv7
(2 failures)
```

Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 4):

It was an issue w/ DerivedData having cruft in it from beta5.  By removing DerivedData completely and then re-running the build, it resolved my issue.

As I was reminded by the awesome Realm team, it's always a good idea to remove DerivedData folder between beta releases.

Comment: You just saved me hours of pulling out what little hair I have left on my head!!! Thanks so much for this!!! BTW, select your answer here as the one that worked - click on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Xcode6-Beta6 was released just yesterday, Realm hasn't been updated to support it. To build Realm with `XCODE_VERSION=6 sh build.sh ios` currently requires Xcode6-Beta5.

You can monitor Realm's GitHub repo ([github.com/realm/realm-cocoa](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa)) to see when Xcode6-Beta6 is supported. Should be today or tomorrow.

EDIT: Please monitor [PR #814](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/814) for progress.